# Laggy video when downloading from m3u8 link with ffmpeg

Tags: encoding, ffmpeg, m3u8

Im trying to download the video in this m3u8 link https://lbs-usp-hls-vod.cmore.se/vod/1aee4/l4fiymehvxx(13287875_ISMUSP).ism/l4fiymehvxx(13287875_ISMUSP).m3u8, and to do that I run this command:

```
ffmpeg -i "https://lbs-usp-hls-vod.cmore.se/vod/1aee4/l4fiymehvxx(13287875_ISMUSP).ism/l4fiymehvxx(13287875_ISMUSP).m3u8" -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4
```

The video downloads fine without any errors, but when I play the video it dosen't look great because it looks like the frame rate is very low, but looking in videoproperties in VLC it says that it is 25 fps which is the same as the original video.

The m3u8 link comes from this website if you need to know that: https://www.tv4play.se/program/taskmaster/13287875

Do someone know what is causing this issue and how to fix it?

Thank you for any advice!

EDIT: I did manage to solve it myself after a lot of research. I just needed to add -fflags +igndts before the -i so the command looked like this

```
ffmpeg -fflags +igndts -i "https://lbs-usp-hls-vod.cmore.se/vod/1aee4/l4fiymehvxx(13287875_ISMUSP).ism/l4fiymehvxx(13287875_ISMUSP).m3u8" -vcodec copy -acodec copy output.mp4
```

Comment: Works for me, update ffmpeg to the latest release (not nightly builld) and also check about VLC version.

Comment: @Harry I just installed the latest version of both ffmpeg and VLC but i still have the same problem.

Comment: ok, i downloaded the full video by copy/pasing your commandline. Quickly investigated in vlc, the video plays fine, jumped to different spots in the video, no issues. But i have a nightly build of ffmpeg:ffmpeg version N-92820-gd702600350 and vlc 3.0.8

Comment: @Harry Ok, this is how the video that I downloaded looks: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/14AyYcK9GIqZ6nR9sJM0J0mNdu1-SsjAZ/view?usp=sharing). Does i look the same or worse than yours?

Comment: Hmm yeah looks exactly the same as the version that i downloaded, plays just perfect on PC and Android. Is it the same on different devices for you?

Comment: Yep, its the same on every device I try. I guess we think differently about whether the downloaded video looks good or not. I think that it looks a lot better when you watch when you watch the video on the website that I am downloading it from. Please take a look at the video on this website and see if you think it looks better or the same as the downloaded one: (https://www.tv4play.se/program/taskmaster/13287875).
Note: You sadly need to register a free account and use a VPN connected to Sweden to watch the video on the website.

Comment: Hmpf sorry, i currently dont have a VPN to sweden, i'll try to get one hehe

Comment: @Harry I did solve it myself after a lot of research. I just needed to add -fflags +igndts before the -i and then it worked.